# C# Datagridview CellClick event does not populate data to textboxes

Tags: c#

So the below codes only works if I load the datasource directly from Datagridview options. It does not work if I refresh the data via scripting. My buttons/event trigger will call these func.Our main focus here is - why didn't the cell click event works after the function 'getrefresh' is called.

```
    public void getclicked()
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) // make sure user select at least 1 row 
    {
        string uid = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + string.Empty;
        string firstn = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value + string.Empty;
        string lastn = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value + string.Empty;
        string amount = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value + string.Empty;
        string getDate = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value + string.Empty;

        InputID.Text = uid;
        InputFN.Text = firstn;
        InputLastN.Text = lastn;
        InputDonate.Text = amount;
        InputDate.Text = getDate;
    }
}



    public void getrefresh()
    {
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        //dataGridView1.Refresh();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Chaos\OneDrive\Project\c#\Donation\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter MyDA = new SqlDataAdapter();

        MyDA.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from DonateTable", conn);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        MyDA.Fill(table);

        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = table;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
        conn.Close();

        dataGridView1.Refresh();


    }
```

Comment: what is strange is when I set a counter on click-event:

MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count));

The click event does work but doesn't show that any item is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your DataGridView's "SelectionMode" property to "FullRowSelect" and in DataGridView's "SelectionChanged" event call your getclicked() method